# Comparing two values in JMeter with JSR223 Assertion

Tags: java, jmeter, comparison, beanshell, jsr223

I have the following scenario:

HTTP Request Sampler
  - RegEx Extractor
  - JSR223 Assertion

The Regex Extractor scrapes for a tag the response. I need to compare that the number of total elements in the array is less than 20k.

Here are the actuals as running the test:
URLCOUNT_matchNr=29471
Given that number the test should fail.

Here is the code that in my JSR223 Assertion(selected Java as the language):

```
String var2 = vars.get("URLCOUNT_matchNr");
Integer result = Integer.valueOf(var2);
if (result > 20000){
    Failure = true;
    log.info(result);
}
```

The test never fails, even after the if condition is met. What am I doing wrong? There are no exceptions either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is good for Beanshell assertion which have `Failure` variable available

But for [JSR223 assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion) just use the following line:

```
 AssertionResult.setFailure(true);
```

> If an error is detected, the script should use AssertionResult.setFailureMessage("message") and AssertionResult.setFailure(true).